# Regex must be 6 digits and last 2 must be 81

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to regex and have literally spent hours on this. I'm trying to build a regex that must have exactly 6 digits and the last two digits have to be 81.

Here is the formula I have so far `\d{6}\d|$|81$`

When I test it out, it matches on fields less that 6 digits, so I'm not sure how to force it to only look for 6 digits ending in `81`.  I'm thinking I'm probably just missing something very simple.  Please help! :)

Comment: Please add a tag to specify which language the regex is in, that will give more visibility to your question.

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
^[0-9]{4}81$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IXZObK/1)

**Details**

- `^` -  [start of string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `[0-9]{4}` - exactly four digits (note that `[0-9]` may be also written as [`\d` shorthand character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) in many regex flavors, and `{4}` is a [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) that can also have a  mnumum and maximum values, like `{4,}` that matches 4 or more occurrences, or `{4,6}` that may match 4, 5 or 6 occurrences)
- `81` - a `81` substring
- `$` - [end of string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!